# What are the variations of Expectation Maximization?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, expectation-maximization, approximation

To explain my question better, I will use this analogy:
In the case of the Gradient-Descent method, we have multiple variations/expansions for the main algorithm, like stochastic gradient descent (SGD) or other variations like ADAM and so on and so forth.

When I came to the EM method, I could not find any variation/expansion for it like SGD (with metaparameters for example epoch and split size) to accelerate the method.

Is there any expansion or variation for the EM method?

Comment: There are tons, so it’s hard to give this question a complete answer. Note also that you can use the gradient descent variants you describe in the M-step, also. This would give you already several variants on EM.

Comment: For a broad-brush overview, you might consider looking at *Section 11.4.8: Other EM variants* of *Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective (2012)* by Murphy. A monograph length reference, *The EM Algorithm and Extensions (2008)* by McLahlan and Krishnan is also cited therein.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following text from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Variants) may dissipate your concerns:

> A number of methods have been proposed to accelerate the sometimes
> slow convergence of the EM algorithm, such as those using conjugate
> gradient and modified Newton's methods (Newton–Raphson).[25] Also, EM
> can be used with constrained estimation methods.
>
> Parameter-expanded expectation maximization (PX-EM) algorithm often
> provides speed up by "us[ing] a `covariance adjustment' to correct the
> analysis of the M step, capitalising on extra information captured in
> the imputed complete data".[26]
>
> Expectation conditional maximization (ECM) replaces each M step with a
> sequence of conditional maximization (CM) steps in which each
> parameter θi is maximized individually, conditionally on the other
> parameters remaining fixed.[27] Itself can be extended into the
> Expectation conditional maximization either (ECME) algorithm.[28]
>
> This idea is further extended in generalized expectation maximization
> (GEM) algorithm, in which is sought only an increase in the objective
> function F for both the E step and M step as described in the As a
> maximization–maximization procedure section.[15] GEM is further
> developed in a distributed environment and shows promising
> results.[29]
>
> It is also possible to consider the EM algorithm as a subclass of the
> MM (Majorize/Minimize or Minorize/Maximize, depending on context)
> algorithm,[30] and therefore use any machinery developed in the more
> general case.